# Файловая система Fedora

Tags: файловая-система, fedora, linux

Помогите пожалуйста.
Когда устанавливал Fedora делал все по умолчанию.
а теперь выясняется, что у меня файловая система забита полностью, хотя на самом диске больше половины свободного места. Как лечить это?

Вывод df:

```
Файловая система                      Размер Использовано  Дост Использовано% Cмонтировано в  
devtmpfs                                742M            0  742M            0% /dev  
tmpfs                                   751M         2,2M  749M            1% /dev/shm  
tmpfs                                   751M         760K  750M            1% /run  
/dev/mapper/vg_travelmate5310-lv_root    47G         9,4G   37G           21% /  
tmpfs                                   751M            0  751M            0%   /sys/fs/cgroup  
tmpfs                                   751M            0  751M            0% /media  
/dev/sda2                               485M          84M  377M           19% /boot  
/dev/mapper/vg_travelmate5310-lv_home    24G          23G   68M          100% /home
```

Вывод mount:

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)  
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)  
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs   (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=759756k,nr_inodes=189939,mode=755)  
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts   (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)  
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel)  
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755)  
/dev/mapper/vg_travelmate5310-lv_root on / type ext4   (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)  
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)  
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)  
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)  
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)  
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup    (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)  
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)  
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)  
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)  
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)  
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)  
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)  
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs   (rw,relatime,fd=23,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)  
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime,seclabel)  
tmpfs on /media type tmpfs   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rootcontext=system_u:object_r:mnt_t:s0,seclabel,mode=755)  
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,relatime)  
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)  
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)  
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)  
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)  
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)  
/dev/mapper/vg_travelmate5310-lv_home on /home type ext4   (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)  
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)  
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/ilia/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon   (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, это вопрос на БитКод

Во-вторых, дайте вывод команды df --human-readable и вывод команды mount
Запросто могло получиться так, что свободное место, например, на корневом разделе, а Ваши файлы лежат на отдельном размере, подмонтированном как /home

Обновляю ответ.

```
/dev/mapper/vg_travelmate5310-lv_root 47G 9,4G 37G 21% /
/dev/mapper/vg_travelmate5310-lv_home 24G 23G 68M 100% /home
```

Вот это говорит нам о том, что место на винчестере поделено нерационально. Дело в том, что ~50GB под систему очень много, хватило б и 20, лишь бы логи и тмп время от времени чистить. А вот на файловую систему, где лежит домашняя папка пользователя и 25ГБ мало, если туда торренты, музыку и видео грузить бочками. Решение проблемы - в текущей ситуации создать каталог в корневом каталоге, например, /files и сгрузить туда все жирные данные, или переразбить винчестер, чтобы на /home было существенно больше места. Еще, конечно, можно для /home не заводить отдельный раздел, а держать все на одном разделе: и систему, и данные, но в случае переустановки это грозит отдельным геморроем с сохранением старых данных.

Comment: вывод команд добавил

Comment: спасибо. чем переразбить винт?

Comment: Если пофиг на сохранность данных - gparted или по старинке fdisk или pdisk.
Если же нужно отресайзить, например, разделы с сохранением файлов, то есть множество платных утилит, среди которых, на мой взгляд, лидируют Acronis DiscDirector и продукт фирмы Paragon. Ну, еще можно вспомнить PartitionMagic от PowerQuest

Answer (score 0):

У вас забился хомяк (/home). Зачем вы туда все стащили непонятно)
Создайте в корне /files и перенесите туда часть своего хлама (видео, мп3 и прочее)